# ordered linked list getting out of order

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having a problem with my linked list. I believe it is right but when I am adding items in I have looked at the addresses of the pointers and multiple pointers will point to the same 'struct.' Here is an example of the output:

The first column is the name, second is when I actually put the item in the list (when a counter equals that number), but they should be ordered by the third column. The fourth column is the address of the struct and the fifth his the address of the next pointer. As you can see A2 and A4 both point to A3, A1's next is null, but I have no pointer to A2 which is causing my problem. A4 should point to A2, A2 to A3, and A3 to A1. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been stuck here for hours. If more explanation is needed, or code, let me know.

Comment: It seems unnecessary to pass a pointer to a pointer to a head. And what happens if the new item should be at the end of the list? You're not setting the last item's next to NULL... There's a couple of problems, it might help to first create a `list_add` function that adds to the end, and then add order. I also face-palmed at the screenshot.

Comment: Yes the screenshot is unnecessary but I was bored. About the NULL at the end, I had thought about that but I have to insert them at a certain time, when I get the data it is all read in from a file and I immediately set the next to NULL. But the list is reordered when another number is added and that is when the problem with the NULL happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it has anything to do with your problem, but in the loop, do not check `current->next != NULL`. That condition means you will never add any node to the end of the list. Instead add a condition `current != NULL` first. Like this:

```
while( (current != NULL ) && ( current->timeNeeded < new_process->timeNeeded ) ){
    temp = current;
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to change that back after messing with it for awhile, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the cause, but seems like you'll have a problem when there's one item in the list with timeNeeded of X, and you add a second item with timeNeeded of X.

After the if, you know that head is not NULL and that the timeNeeded of the incoming node is not less than the head. The first iteration of the loop is looking at head again. If the timeNeeded values are equal for the head and incoming nodes, the loop will never run, giving you a temp and current that point to head.

From that point, your logic basically says "set head->next to the incoming, and set incoming->next to the head."

You didn't list your timeNeeded values in your original post, so it's probably unrelated, but may be something to look at? (e.g. put a "<=" or a ">=" in there somewhere to catch the list-of-two-nodes case)

Comment: Ah, the "should be ordered by the 3rd column" implies that those are your timeNeeded values. Still, may be useful?

Comment: Come to think of it, this (imagined) issue would likely exist whenever the incoming node and head have the same timeNeeded value -- not just in the 2-node list.

Comment: Yes that was a good suggestion, and while it didn't fix my current issue, I probably would've ran into it eventually.